# Automate deployment to the Android Developer Console

Tags: android, automation, google-play

Are there any libraries that will help me deploy to the Google Play Android Developer Console?

I would like to automatically:

1. Upload a new APK
2. Update the text for "Recent Changes"
3. Post the form, i.e. clicking on "Save"

I'm using Python for my automation, but any other language will be helpful.

Comment: Searching for this too for a pretty long time now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google releases en July 2014 a new API for automatic deploy to Alpha/Beta and Production channels!

take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/?rd=1)

Api features:

- Uploading new versions of an app Releasing apps, by assigning APKs to
  various Tracks (alpha, beta, staged rollout, or production)
- Creating and modifying Google Play Store listings, including localized text
  and graphics and multi-device screenshots

Answer (score 5):

We are developing an open-source tool for automating deploying an app to Google Play:
https://github.com/onepf/AppDF/tree/master/tools/uploader

You can check its code that does exactly what you need by encapsulating a webkit control and working with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA, I have built a open source plugin about it. [DroidLane](https://github.com/Jintin/DroidLane)

It uses the google api to upload apk and also the recent change text.
You can define multiple profile or group apks in one push.
Recent change text also support multiple language.
All the certificate are encrypt in AES by your given password. It's pretty safe.

You can search the plugin in your IDE or download in [JetBrains site](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8068).

See https://github.com/Jintin/DroidLane for more information. 
You are always welcome if you have any question or want feature.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/). It works for both iOS and Android and does a lot more besides app store deployment:

> - Automate the entire app store deployment process.
> - Create a repeatable custom workflow to build, upload and distribute new releases to the app store
> - Upload and manage all of your app’s metadata including screenshots
> - Automatically submit new versions of your app for review